# Drop down all images ... almost working. How to

Tags: css

At [this site](http://chesapeakerepair.missionmedia.net/)  when you hover over the nav title "Service,"  a drop down appears.   Then when you hover witin sub nav & mouseover title "Repair," you see a 2ndary menu appear..

I want to move that 2ndary yellow sub-sub-menu up to align it with it's parent "Repair."

Now I have been able to do just that by adding top: 0; and margin-top: -40px to ID property:  nav li ul li ul .  But, adding top:0 and or any margin to nav li ul li ul causes the 2ndary yellow sub-sub nav to display always rather only on hover.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I figured it out ... needed to change(decrease it) the width in nav li ul li ul

Answer (score 1):

Change the style of your second level UL element to as below(i.e. make top:0):

```
#nav li ul li ul {
    position:absolute;
      top:0;
    width:175px;
}
```